# Changing <input type= color> behaviour from single click to double click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

By default clicking a  will bring up a window that lets you pick a custom colour.

I want to do this with a double click instead.

I can stop single click from working with e.preventDefault but I can't work out how to make doubleClick do this behaviour instead.

What I want:

```
handleDbClick = (e) => {
  //opens colour selection box
}
<input type="color" onDoubleClick={this.handleDbClick}/>
```

Solution:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
  if(e.detail === 1) {
     e.preventDefault()
     //do stuff for one click
  }
  //open colour selection box
}

<input type="color" onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add relevant smallest set of code that reproduces the issue and describe your specific challenge based upon that

Comment: You could just use the [dblclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event) event to open it. Or check the [event.detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event#usage_notes) for the amount of consecutive clicks.

Comment: event.detail works great thank you! Really struggled to find something like that when trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `event.detail` to check number of consecutive clicks, and use `event.preventDefault()` if they are not `2`.

```js
let input = document.querySelector("#colorInput");
input.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.detail !== 2) e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input type="color" id="colorInput">
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
 const colorInput = document.getElementById("colorInput")
        let count = 0;
        let interval
        
        colorInput.addEventListener('click', e => {
            count++
            clearInterval(interval)
            interval = setInterval(() => {
             count = 0   
            }, 300)
            if(count === 2) {
                count = 0
            } else {

                e.preventDefault();
            }
        })
```

or this:

```
const colorInput = document.getElementById("colorInput")
        
        colorInput.addEventListener('click', e => {
            if(event.detail !== 2) {
                e.preventDefault()
            }
        })
```